# REST client with TLS returns SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure

Tags: java, rest, certificate, tls1.2

I am tying to integrate with RESTful API,and i have this utility method to send REST request and get the response

```
    BufferedReader br;
        HttpURLConnection con = null;

        try {
            URL obj = new URL(url);
            con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

            con.setReadTimeout(httpReadTimeOut);
            con.setRequestMethod("POST");

            for (String key : requestTypeMap.keySet()) {
                con.setRequestProperty(key, requestTypeMap.get(key));
            }

            String jsonRequest = gson.toJson(request);
            CommonUtilityLogger.debug("json request is :: " + jsonRequest);

            con.setDoOutput(true);
            DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
            wr.writeBytes(jsonRequest);
            wr.flush();
            wr.close();

            if (con.getResponseCode() != 200) {
                CommonUtilityLogger.error("failed : HTTP error code : " + con.getResponseCode());
            }

            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader((con.getInputStream())));

            return (T) gson.fromJson(br, responseType);
```

In the third party API documentation, it says i have to use TLS certificates and they include many files related to that

```
Test Certificate 1231181189.key 
Test Certificate 1231181189.p7b 
Test Certificate 1231181189.p12 
Test Certificate 1231181189.pem 
TLS Root CA.pem
```

now every time i try to call these service i got

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:154)
```

what i am missing here, i cannot find it out

Answer (score 1):

Try downloading certificate for the REST API from browser and add that certificate in your truststore.jks file.

Follow this link to create keystore and truststore:[Create keystore and truststore](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/347116/how-to-create-keystore-and-truststore-using-self-signed-certificate)